# Godot doesn't import glTF material shaders correctly

Tags: blender, godot, gltf

I have a model that I am using as my gameworld in Godot and I am putting some textures on it in Blender. When exporting the model to .glb it seems to not be exporting some of the materials correctly.

The ones that are an image texture that I scaled using mapping.
[image]

It just skips the first two nodes. When I disconnect them the material looks like it does in Godot.

What it should look like (what it looks like in Blender):
[image]

What it looks like in Godot:
[image]

There also are some materials that use mix shaders to mix images together. These are also skipped and it just uses one of the two instead of mixing them.

[image]

What it should look like:
[image]

What it looks like in Godot:
[image]

The F is from an image with text that is overlayed ontop of the other image.

I am not really sure if these issues lie with the glTF format and certain shaders just don't work with it or that Godot doesn't want to import them.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day,

Rover

Comment: I just reimported my model into a new Blender file and it seems Blender doesn't export the mix shaders into the .glb file at all. None of them are there. The mapping and texture coordinates are there though.

Answer (score 4):

In general, arbitrary node graphs cannot be exported from Blender — see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57541/43930 for the long explanation of that. To ensure that the material will export correctly, you'll need to refer to the documentation for the [Blender glTF exporter](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html) and configure your material accordingly. For more complicated effects, you can also [bake Blender nodes down to simpler textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake).

Comment: What Don said. But for that first case in your question, it's possible Godot might not support the glTF extension called `KHR_texture_transform`, and if so that would explain why the texture transform didn't get applied.